# Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed Error in Content provider's query class

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

Similar Questions about this particular error message have been asked several times in Stack Overflow. I could not find one that matches my situation. So here it goes.

I am getting this error in the Content provider's `query` method when I turn on Strict mode. My Content provider's query method calls `queryDirections(...)` below. I am simply calling the `db.query` method and return the cursor. How can I close this cursor? The compiler complains on the line return statement below that cursor is not closed. Detailed error message is below.
thanks.

Content Provider

```
    private Cursor queryDirections(Uri uri, String[] columns, 
        String selection, String[] selectionArguments,
        String sortOrder) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = mySqliteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            return db.query(C.Db.TABLE_DIRECTIONS, columns, 
                     selection, selectionArguments, null, null, sortOrder);
    }
```

Called from Activity

```
continued...
case R.id.spinnerStops:
    AsyncQueryHandler handler = new AsyncQueryHandler(getContentResolver()) {
        @Override
        protected void onQueryComplete(int token, Object cookie, Cursor stopCursor) {
            stopCursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = stopCursor.getColumnIndex(Stop.KEY_TAG);
            if (stopCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                mStopTag = stopCursor.getString(columnIndex);
                stopCursor.close();
            }
        };
    };
    handler.startQuery(1, null, C.ContentUri.STOP, 
                           new String[] { 
                               C.Db.TABLE_STOPS + "." + Stop.KEY_TITLE,
                               C.Db.TABLE_STOPS + "." + Stop.KEY_TAG }, 
                       "Stops._id=" + id, null, null);
    break;
```

Also I have overridden onStop for my two spinner adapters

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    MyLogger.log("closing cursor");
    try {
        if (mStopsAdapter != null) {

            mStopsAdapter.getCursor().close();
            mStopsAdapter = null;
        }
        if (mDirectionAdapter != null) {
            mDirectionAdapter.getCursor().close();
            mDirectionAdapter = null;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    super.onStop();

}
```

ErrorMessage

```
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918): Finalizing a Cursor that has not been deactivated or closed. database = /data/data/com.thuptencho.torontotransitbus/databases/appdb.db, table = directions, query = SELECT tag FROM directions WHERE _id=-999
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:98)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:50)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1161)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1032)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1200)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at com.thuptencho.torontotransitbus.provider.TheContentProvider.queryDirections(TheContentProvider.java:169)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at com.thuptencho.torontotransitbus.provider.TheContentProvider.query(TheContentProvider.java:109)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:372)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:315)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.content.AsyncQueryHandler$WorkerHandler.handleMessage(AsyncQueryHandler.java:79)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-31 23:30:23.295: E/StrictMode(28918):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Comment: If you'd like to post your code on where the `Cursor` is being used, that might help pinpoint where the cursor.close() type of call should be added.

Comment: I have edited to add code related to `ContentResolver` call.

Answer (score 0):

`Cursor`s returns from a `ContentProvider` must be closed by the receiving component (`Activity`, `Service`, etc) and not by the `ContentProvider` itself.

Comment: and how do you do that in the context of Search suggestions?

Comment: @axd - assuming you mean [custom search suggestions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html), that should take care of its own Cursor.

Comment: that is precisely my problem... the framework is NOT closing the cursor, and I found out via Strict.

Comment: @axd - from looking at the [source code for SearchView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/SearchView.java#187), it definitely does close the Cursor (that's what [changeCursor()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/CursorAdapter.java#342) does), but it does it asynchronously in `onDetachedFromWindow()`, which may show up as a false positive in StrictMode.